Twilio Recording Fetch returns not found
ADDING SOME BACKGROUND INFO HERE:
I have a google apps script that emails me a Twilio recording when I receive a voicemail in Twilio Studio. Basically after I prompt the caller to record a voicemail I run Http Get request to my Google Web App with a few parameters about the call including the recording url which I would like to log on a spreadsheet and email to me, a basic voicemail-to-Email idea.
When I'm trying to fetch the recording resource in google apps script with UrlFetchApp to add as an attachment in the email I get the following error The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxx/Recordings/RExxxxxxxxx was not found.
What's interesting is that when I hardcode the Twilio recording url into the function it works, but when the recording url is passed in as a parameter it gets this error. I logged the url to the spreadsheet before the point of the error and the recording url comes through.
Any help is appreciated.


function doGet(e){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('vm');

try{
var p = e.parameter;
var from = p.from;
var received = p.received;
var u = p.recording;
var url = String(u);
var length = p.length;
var email = p.email;
var ext = p.ext;
var fromDashes = from.slice(-10,-7)+"-"+from.slice(-7,-4)+"-"+from.slice(-4);
var receivedDashes = received.slice(-10,-7)+"-"+received.slice(-7,-4)+"-"+received.slice(-4);

  //time script ran
const d = new Date();
const t = d.toLocaleString();
const split = t.split(',');
const time = split[1];

var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var theDate = curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year;

ss.appendRow([theDate,time,receivedDashes,fromDashes,length,ext,email,url]); // this logs the full url

var fileName = "VM_" + fromDashes + "_" + theDate

var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getBytes();

blob = Utilities.newBlob(blob, 'audio/x-wav', fileName);

var message = {
  to: email,
  subject: "[New] Voicemail for "+ext,
  htmlBody: "<h3>You received a new voicemail from: " + fromDashes + "</h3>For: "+ext+"<br><br>Recieved at: "+receivedDashes+"<br>Length: "+length+"<br><br><a href=" + url + ">Listen to Voicemail</a>", //<br><br><a href=" + callBackUrl + ">Call "+fromDashes+"</a>",
  attachments: [blob]
};

MailApp.sendEmail(message);

}
catch(e){
  ss.appendRow([e])
}
}




What is the difference between url of Whats intresting is that when I hardcode the url into the function it works and url of but when the url is passed in as a parameter it gets this error.? And, can you provide the detailed request for your Web Apps?

That's what I can't figure out if i hardcode the var like this var url = "https://xxxxxx.com" it works, but when I pass the var into the function it gets the error.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the answers to my 2 questions. In order to correctly understand your question, can you do the following steps? 1. Add a script DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(e)) just under the line of function doGet(e){. 2. Reflect the latest script to Web Apps using a sample URL. 3. Run doGet from your client. 4. Provide the value in the created file sample.txt and the valid sample URL.

I followed your direction and I see the full url in the sample.txt file, and it works, but when I remove that line of code it doesn't work, why is that?

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from I followed your direction and I see the full url in the sample.txt file, and it works, but when I remove that line of code it doesn't work, why is that?, I cannot still understand your situation and the answer to my questions. So, I cannot also answer to your new question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

followed your direction and I see the full url in the sample.txt file, and it works What do you mean it works? Just logging to sample.txt make the rest of your script work?

Yes its the weirdest thing when I keep that line of code in the rest of the script works when I remove it the UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getBytes() returns an error from Twilio resource not found the only thing I can think of is Twilio needs another second or 2 for the resource to be available since it was just created and the creating a file slows the script down

Adding  Utilities.sleep(120*1000) should confirm your theory. @jack If you confirm, please add an answer.

After some help from the comments from @Tanaike and @TheMaster I discovered that it seems Twilio needs another 2 seconds for the resource to be available from its servers and the recording resource wasn't found since the script ran immediately after the recording was made.
A simple fix was adding a 2 second pause to the beginning of the script like this:
function doGet(e){

Utilities.sleep(2000); // This 2 second sleep solved the issue

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('vm');

try{
var p = e.parameter;
var from = p.from;
var received = p.received;
var u = p.recording;
var url = String(u);
var length = p.length;
var email = p.email;
var ext = p.ext;
var fromDashes = from.slice(-10,-7)+"-"+from.slice(-7,-4)+"-"+from.slice(-4);
var receivedDashes = received.slice(-10,-7)+"-"+received.slice(-7,-4)+"-"+received.slice(-4);

  //time script ran
const d = new Date();
const t = d.toLocaleString();
const split = t.split(',');
const time = split[1];

var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var theDate = curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year;

ss.appendRow([theDate,time,receivedDashes,fromDashes,length,ext,email,url]); // this logs the full url

var fileName = "VM_" + fromDashes + "_" + theDate

var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getBytes();

blob = Utilities.newBlob(blob, 'audio/x-wav', fileName);

var message = {
  to: email,
  subject: "[New] Voicemail for "+ext,
  htmlBody: "<h3>You received a new voicemail from: " + fromDashes + "</h3>For: "+ext+"<br><br>Recieved at: "+receivedDashes+"<br>Length: "+length+"<br><br><a href=" + url + ">Listen to Voicemail</a>", //<br><br><a href=" + callBackUrl + ">Call "+fromDashes+"</a>",
  attachments: [blob]
};

MailApp.sendEmail(message);

}
catch(e){
  ss.appendRow([e])
}
}

